# How to find error passport-local-mongoose?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I use MERN stack and in authention I want to use passport-local-mongoose. But in my code I cannot find errors. Please help me I tried this problem.
after login or register i want to know req.user in `/current` this route.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();


app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
  secret: "Our little secret.",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/QuizApp", {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex:true, useUnifiedTopology:true});


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  username: String,
  password: String,
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});




app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
  req.logout();
});

app.post("/register", function(req, res){

  User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
      });
    }
  });

});

app.post("/login", function(req, res){

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  req.login(user, function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        console.log("ish bitdi");
    });
    }
  });

});

app.get('/current', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user);
});

app.listen(3001, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3001.");
});
```

And this is my axios send code. I use dispatch react-redux

```
import { USER_LOGIN_FAIL, USER_LOGIN_REQUEST, USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, USER_REGISTER_FAIL, USER_REGISTER_REQUEST, USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS } from "../constants/all";
import axios from "axios";

const user_Register = (email, password) => async (dispatch) =>{
    dispatch({ type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST });
    try {
        const {data} = await axios( {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                "username": email,
                "password": password
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:3001/register"
        });  
        
        dispatch({ type: USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: data });

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: USER_REGISTER_FAIL, error: error.message});
    }
}

const user_Login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) =>{
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST });
    try {
        const {data} = await axios( {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                "username": email,
                "password": password
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:3001/login"
        });  
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL, error: error.message});
    }
}

export {user_Register, user_Login};
```

Comment: And why do you think there is an error? Please explain the full issue.

Comment: I send username and password to backend. It is go well. But register or login cannot work. in register route console.log("ish bitdi") work. but after /current route I cannot get req.user. I too dont understand why it be. If you find some error please help me

Comment: Let me guess, you are calling these URLs via Ajax?

Comment: no I send username and password using axios

Comment: yes, same thing, and is a common misunderstanding - sessions work by remembering that the client was previously logged in, in your case, you send a request to the server from the browser _asynchronously_ (AJAX request) which means the cookie does not save. You need to make your login request a standard browser request (i.e. form post) to allow the browser to store the cookie to allow subsequent requests will be able to load the session. Alternatively, you need to store that cookie when it comes back from the AJAX request.

Comment: and Can i do it?

Comment: Can you do what?

Comment: can i cookie save in this code?

Comment: The express session & passport will already be doing that, the issue would appear that the client isn't respecting the cookie. You can check by inspecting the cookies in the browser tab, you can check if both the cookie is being sent back in the AJAX call and whether the browser is persisting it (my guess is, it's not)

Comment: I found some errors. I send username and password and id this object change in passport.serializeUser. and why it be?